# DDR2 RAM: Effective RAM dual channel frequency

Tags: memory, ddr2, dual-channel

Assuming the following DDR2 dual channel RAM setup on a Gigabyte P35-DS4 rev 1.0 board:

```
Channel 0:
Bank #0 : DDR2-800
Bank #1 : DDR2-800

Channel 1:
Bank #0 : DDR2-1066
Bank #1 : DDR2-1066
```

Will the

- memory frequency be **800 MHz for both channels** or
- will each channel run at its specific maximum frequency (**800 for channel 0, 1066 for channel 1**)?

Comment: I'm 99.94% sure that both channels will downgrade to the slowest RAM speed of 800 MHz

Comment: The manual for your motherboard should describe what will happen in a case like this.  In most cases lower clocked memory will cause all memory to run at that speed.

Comment: Typical behavious in all motherboards where I looked it is to drop the speed to the lowest common setting. In this case to 400MHz (the DDR2-800 speed).